# Angular, body add css overflow:hidden if modal is open and remove it if closed?

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, simplemodal

Is there any way to put the body in overflow:hidden when I open a modal? In this way I can scroll only the modal and not the body element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this solution

typescript file

```
constructor() {
  const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.classList.add('modal-open');
}
ngOnDestroy() {
   const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
   body.classList.remove('modal-open');
}
```

css file

```
.modal-open { overflow-y: hidden; }
```

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but struggled with the same issue, and since this is an Angular issue, if you are using AngularCDK you can also use this styling class instead of your own: `cdk-global-scrollblock`. Also to put on body